# discordpy - How to grab member from message in wait_for method

Tags: python, discord.py

When somebody clicks on a button, I want to prompt them to send a message containing a user mention. I then want to grab the user from their response and add it to `first category`. Also, I want to set timeout for this input, which is why I used `wait_for()`.

My problem is I can't specify `m` as a User and always get `asyncio.TimeoutError`

```
class LevelButtons(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="Setting up first category", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def conf_level(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await self.message.channel.send("Send a @user who will be in the first category")
        def check(m: discord.Member):
            return m == discord.Member and m.channel == self.message.channel
        try:
            m = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=10, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await self.message.channel.send('Received no input so operation was aborted')
        else:
            self.first_level.append(m)
            await self.message.channel.send(f"{m.content} added in the first category")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `discord.Member`'s attribute `mentions` which returns  a list of mentions.

```
class LevelButtons(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="Setting up first category", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def conf_level(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await self.message.channel.send("Send a @user who will be in the first category")
        def check(m: discord.Member):
            return m == discord.Member and m.channel == self.message.channel
        try:
            m = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=10, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await self.message.channel.send('Received no input so operation was aborted')
        else:
            self.first_level.append(m.mentions[0]) #  Takes first mention in message
            await self.message.channel.send(f"{m.mentions[0]} added in the first category")
```

Also, I assume you want to check if the message author is the button user, simply change `m == discord.Member` to

```
def check(m):
    return m.author.id == interaction.user.id and m.channel == self.message.channel
```

Keep in mind that `bot.wait_for('message')` returns `discord.Message`

Documentation:
[discord.Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message), [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member), [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Additional notes:
Interaction is not responded to, `self.message` is unnecessary with `interaction.message` or more contextually `interaction.channel`

[discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction)

Comment: Thank you for additional  `interaction` explanation :)